# How to use filter in ansible to extrat a value from string

Tags: ansible

Could you please help me, in my ansible role I need to extract (with filter) three  values from :

```
adopt_openjdk_version: 11.0.6+0.18.0
```

I would like

```
java_major_version: 11
java_release : 11.0.6
openj9_release: 0.18.0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split string:

```
set_fact:
  java_major_version: "{{ adopt_openjdk_version.split('.')[0]}}"
  java_release: "{{ adopt_openjdk_version.split('+')[0]}}"
  openj9_release: "{{ adopt_openjdk_version.split('+')[1]}}"
```

Comment: Many TKS, it's ok for me.